# Matching a variable to an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, mouseover

So I have an array of strings (I think I did it right):

```
var editableObjects = ['.body-copy', 'img', '.subhead', '.meta', '.caption', '.hyperlink', '.bullet'];
```

A function that gets the element that is under the mouse:

```
function getMouseElement(event) {
    var posX = event.clientX,
    posY = event.clientY;
    // get the element that is located under the mouse 
   var overElem = document.elementFromPoint(posX, posY);
   return overElem;
}
```

And then this jquery listener that watches for mouseover on ".editable" elements:

```
$('#wrapper').on('mouseover', '.editable', function(event) {
var m = getMouseElement(event);
console.log(m.className); /*This correctly returns the tag of the element under the mouse*/
for (var c = editableObjects.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
    var o = editableObjects[c];
    if (m.className = o) {
        console.log(m + ' matches ' + o);
    } else {}
}
});
```

What I'm trying to do, is have the function look through the list and see if the element the mouse is over matches one of the string objects in `editableObjects`. My for-loop is supposed to check the variable for any of those matching elements, and then do something if there is a match. But after many hours, I can only get the for loop to return a match for every object in the variable, whether it actually matches or not.

Comment: The problem is the '=' rather then '==' in the if statement. A single '=' is an assignment operator whereas '==' is used to compare.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your intent, but if you need to determine when a `mouseover` event is fired over certain elements why not simply put the event listener on those elements rather than the parent and then figuring cursor position? i.e., `$('.body-copy').on('mouseover',... $('.subhead').on('mouseover'...` etc.

Comment: I would just make the second argument of the .on function a selector for the elements of your array.

Comment: These are dynamic elements, and from what I understand, they need delegated listeners on a containing element in order to be fired on events. I was trying to fire the delegated listener for mouseover on ".editable" class, which is a class that all these elements would have, but I needed it to check for certain types of elements for my function.

Answer (score 2):

You assign a value by using `=` in your `if (m.className = o)`, to check for equality, use `==` or `===`.
It would also be easier to use a built in function than the loop. A simple `indexOf()` will do the trick:

```
$('#wrapper').on('mouseover', '.editable', function(event) {
    var m = getMouseElement(event);
    if (editableObjects.indexOf(m.className) > -1) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

or using es6 `includes()`

```
if (editableObjects.includes(m.className))
```

Comment: I just tried altering the comparison to == or ===, and nothing is being returned now. I'm assuming now that it's a matter of my variable/object being created improperly, but not sure.

Comment: I just got _something_ to work by swtiching the `m.classname` to `m.localName`. I'm able to match it to a tag, but not a class, yet. I need to be able to match the element to a list of tags _or_ classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
$('#wrapper').on('mouseover', '.editable', function(event) {
  var m = getMouseElement(event);
  console.log(m.className); /*This correctly returns the tag of the 
  element under the mouse*/
  for (var c = editableObjects.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
     var o = editableObjects[c];
     if (m.className == o) {
        console.log(m + ' matches ' + o);
     } else {...}
   }
});
```

This line: `if (m.className == o) {` compare the values, while your line: `if (m.className = o) {` test if it can assign the value... that should put you in the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. It seemed to have been a problem of the elements in my variable not being recognized correctly, I'm guessing because they are strings and not objects or actual elements. The "include" method works:

```
$('#wrapper').on('mouseover', '.editable', function(event) {
var m = getMouseElement(event);
// console.log(m.className); /*This correctly returns the class of the element under the mouse*/
for (var c = editableObjects.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
    var o = editableObjects[c];
    if (m.className.includes(o)) {
        console.log(m + ' matches ' + o);
        // addToolTips(m);
    } else if (m.localName.includes(o)) {
        console.log(m + ' matches ' + o);
        // addToolTips(m);
    }
}
});
```